# Why don't we close, merge MORE questions as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

##### I bewildered at finding so many questions that nobody closed or merged as duplicates, as acknowledged by [Mauro Allegranza](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/61623/how-is-the-claim-i-am-in-new-york-only-if-i-am-in-america-the-same-as-if-i-am#comment170381_61623). Why do we shun closing and merging?

### The original  is [How can we reason about "if P then Q" or "P only if Q" statements in propositional logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/4089).

[What is the relationship of "if A then B" and "A only if B"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/14320)
[Are "If P then Q" and "Q only if P" equivalent?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/28331)
[The difference between "P if Q" and "P only if Q"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/40878)
[How is the claim "I am in New York only if I am in America" the same as "If I am in New York, then I am in America?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/61623)
[How does "if p, then q" compare to "p only if q"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/96568)

### [What are some good resources for philosophy in laymen's terms?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/945)

[How to get started with philosophy without getting overwhelmed quickly?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2115)
[A book that introduces Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/3551)
[Where should I start to learn about philosophy in general?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/4456)
[Books about a broad introduction of philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/7955)
[What are some simple ways to start learning philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/21700)
[Indroductory books about Philosophy for young people](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/36874)
[Most effective ways to self-learn philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/36953)
[Philosophy book indications for beginners](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/46355)
[If I had to read one book on philosophy, what should it be?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/68066)

### [Rigorous, modern introductions to informal reasoning and critical thinking?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/49094)

[How can I develop my critical thinking skills?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/8145)
[How do you progress in self-learning Critical Thinking, after completing an introductory textbook?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/30572)
[Critical Thinking Course - A Good Choice?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/33852)
[What Is Critical Thinking, and How Does One Go About Learning It?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/67956)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have addressed most of the duplicates you point (some were not exact duplicates and were more specific than the original question, and others were already closed as duplicates). Thank you for the effort making the list. Now it's up to the rest of the members of the community since as the accepted answer says, it takes 5 close votes for the question to be effectively marked as a duplicate. I wonder why, with the amount of users that have higher reputation than I do, none of them flagged them as duplicates. Maybe they don't even know they can do it? In any case, let me know if you notice any more cluster of similar questions.

Comment: Many users do not have the time or motivation to live up to one of the core principles of StackExchange, which is self-governance of the community.

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer:

Because there are not enough users who search for and mark as possible duplicates.

Before you think that this was the moderators' task...no, it is not. Moderators should only handle tasks that only they can handle due to additional privileges. We got enough to do with these. Marking a question as a possible duplicate is a vote-to-close reason and can be done by anyone with 500+ reputation.